# Как подружить luit и cp866?

Tags: linux, кодировка, utf-8

Linux. utf8.

```
[root@pandora ~]# luit -list | grep 866
```

не дает нам ничего, а надо чтобы была 866 кодировка. Как научить luit понимать её?

p.s. xorg-x11-apps последний стоит. CentOS 5.6

**UPD**

Ну я, в общем, все сделал. Сейчас поясню. Для того, чтобы с linux ходить в консоль винды, надо иметь поддержку cp866 в консоли.

Итак, нам надо пропатчить luit (это тулза, которая фоном поток конвертит из чужеродной локали в текущую), чтобы она понимала `cp866`. У меня `CentOS 5.x`, делал для него.

Что я сделал.

1. Убедился, что такой локали у меня нет `locale -a | grep 866`
2. Проверил, что charmaps для 866 присутствует `ll /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/IBM866.gz`
3. Создал локаль IBM866. `localedef -i ru_RU -f IBM866 ru_RU.IBM866`. подготовка завершена, теперь надо патчить luit

Скачал исходники `xorg-x11-apps.src.rpm`, развернул и нашел в исходниках архив `luitа`, развернул его и нашел там файл `charset.c`.

В нем, в описании массива:

```
 FontencCharsetRec fontencCharsets[] = {
```

Добавил строку:

```
{"IBM866", T_128, 0, "ibm-cp866", 0x80, 0, 0}
```

Затем в описании

```
LocaleCharsetRec localeCharsets[] = {
```

Добавил

```
{ "ibm866", 0, 2, "ASCII", NULL, "IBM866", NULL, NULL}
```

Сохранил, затарил само дерево luit, перекомпилировал в новый rpm, установил и получил пофиксенный и рабочий комплект.

Вот как это теперь выглядит: [win2lin http://dl.dropbox.com/u/66475831/Sites/inet/luit.gif](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/66475831/Sites/inet/luit.gif)

Comment: Вынесите, пожалуйста, ваше решение в отдельный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

описанная в вопросе проблема очень устарела.

уже [2011/10/30](http://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.log.html#t20111030) в `luit` была внесена правка:

> 2011/10/30
>
> add entries to the locale-charset table to correspond with the font-encoding table, making it possible to use locales defined with each named charset (reported by Andrey Ivanov, also reported in Freedesktop [#41857](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41857))

так что, если в вашем дистрибутиве более старая версия, то можно [скачать](http://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html#download) и собрать актуальную версию.