# Запуск древней программы на современной ОС

Tags: linux, кодировка, консоль

Программа `sb_pilot` у меня есть от *4 апр 2012*. При запуске в консоле отображаются только ascii символы. Русские буквы не передаются на терминал совсем никак (даже в strace ни намека). Программа переводит курсор там где латинская буква и печатает оттуда. Там где кирилица должна быть - просто не рендерит ничего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вывод терминала текстом](https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/627bb7b1ca88f2b5ca130133bff6d002)

Пробовал скрипты от УКМ - не помогают. Судя по ним должно работать в koi8u, но даже кракозябр не получил.

Строки внутри бинаря в cp866, слинкован с ncurces 5.

Comment: Програмка то не моя,)

Comment: Это программа для линукса? "Русские буквы не передаются на терминал совсем никак" - а они должны? я бы не удивился поддержке только ppcs

Comment: Линукс. Консоль. Какой эмулятор?)

Comment: Эльф 32битный, i586

Comment: Внутри бинаря строки в cp866)

Comment: Должна работать в koi8u судя по скриптам, но не воспринимает эти костыли сейчас

Comment: Берём любую виртуальную машину и ставим любую необходимую ОС тех годов, если проблема действительно в этом.

Comment: посмотреть бы вывод в hex

Comment: [уж десять лет luit отлично работает с cp866](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433075/178576)

Comment: В хексе управляшки двигают курсор, русских букв нет. Управляшки через эскейп-пробел(один байт)- латиница.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это другая программа ж..

Comment: Как вариант - перекодировать строки внутри бинарника.

Comment: @eri, luit — это перекодировщик-на-лету. см. [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/luit)  и/или что-нибудь менее формальное.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не берет. наверное изза libncurses.so.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заработало в комплексе мер:

Скачал и распаковал [lib32tinfo5](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lib32tinfo5) и [lib32ncurses5](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lib32ncurses5) в папку с программой. Версия поближе к оригиналу. Потому что у меня ncurces 6 с совместимостью с 5, а не 5.

Сгенерировал локаль ru_RU.KOI8-R.

```
sed -i '/^#ru_RU.KOI8-R/s/^#//' /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen
```

Запускается так

```
#export LANG=ru_RU.KOI8-R
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
#export TERM=vt100
export TERM=xterm-vt220
luit -encoding koi8-r ./sb_pilot 11
```